# What version of Spring framework is required for Spring batch 3.0.7?

Tags: spring-batch

I am getting into the following error when I use Batch 3.0.7 with Spring framework 4.3.9.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(CustomEditorConfigurer.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:532
    ...
```

Apparently, the "string" in question is "org.springf
ramework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]".

I am able to reproduce the error with the most basic Batch configuration such as:

```
<batch:step id="basicStep">
</batch:step>
```

So I am wondering if Batch 3.0.7 has an issue working with Spring framework 4.3.9. I tried to look for information regarding Batch dependencies but I couldn't find any for 3.0.7 version.

Does anyone know if compatibility is the problem here or perhaps something else is going on?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: Can you please provide the code that is causing the error?

Comment: I don't see any stack traces in the log other than what I posted above. And that trace results when I enable the XML configuration also listed above. So I am not sure what code should I provide. I am using [Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/) if that helps. - Thanks, Raghu.

Comment: A more complete version of configuration file can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110270/how-to-debug-classcastexception-in-customeditorconfigurer-postprocessbeanfactory). I posted separate question here with "batch" tag as the other question was talking more from spring framework point of view.